# Mac file/dir creation problems with Java

Tags: java, macos, io

I have been writing a program for a group of Minecrafters and their Modpack, the program is a custom launcher. The problem is when Mac-OSX users try using the program it has problems with making its folder in `/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/.melbvicminecraft/`, I know it is a permissions problem, but I want to find a way to let them use the application without the need for them to have root permissions.

Main.java:

```
public static File getMinecraftDir()
{
    String os = getOS();
    String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home", ".");

    if(os == "win")
    {
        String appdata = System.getenv("APPDATA");
        String location = appdata != null ? appdata : userHome;

        return new File(location);
    }
    else if(os == "mac")
    {
        return new File(userHome, "Library/Application Support/");
    }
    else
        return new File(userHome);
}
```

MinecraftLoginThread.java:

```
/**
 * Make a new Minecraft login handler with the selected dir
 * 
 * @param settings Settings file located on the <strong>server</strong>
 * @param server The content server
 * @param minecraftDir minecraftDir The selected Minecraft dir
 */
public MinecraftLoginThread(SettingsFile settings, String server, File minecraftDir)
{
    try 
    {           
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        try 
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch(Exception e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try
    {
        Main.logger.debug("Minecraft dir: " + minecraftDir.getAbsolutePath());
        Main.logger.debug("Minecraft exists: " + minecraftDir.exists());

        if(!minecraftDir.exists())
        {
            try 
            {
                minecraftDir.setWritable(true);
                minecraftDir.setReadable(true);

                if(minecraftDir.mkdirs())
                    Main.logger.debug("Made new Minecraft dir: " + minecraftDir.getAbsolutePath());
                else
                    Main.killError("Failed to make new Minecraft dir!");
            } 
            catch (Exception e) { Main.killError(e.toString()); }
        }


        if(!(new File(minecraftDir, "lastLogin").exists()))
            (new File(minecraftDir, "lastLogin")).createNewFile();

        this.lastLogin = new SettingsFile((new File(minecraftDir, "lastLogin")));
        this.lastLogin.load();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.settings = settings;
    this.server = server;
    this.backgroundManager = new BackgroundManager(server + settings.getSetting("net.melbvicmc.launcher.mlbl"));
    this.mcDir = minecraftDir;
    this.optionsDialog = new MinecraftOptionsDialog(this);
    loadJFrameLayout();
}
```

Here is the log from a mac: [The log](http://pastebin.com/BviSi9Ss)

The application can be found here: [Launcher Download](http://hachisoftware.com/data/melbvicminecraft/Melb-Vic%20Minecraft.jar)

Comment: Source code? What error(s) do you get?

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg I will upload the source code to git and will link it in the post, I'm also not getting any exceptions, and `mkdirs()` is returning true but not making the folder

Comment: Where are you checking that `mkdirs()` is returning `true`?

Comment: I just changed it to check on make

Comment: Strange, and whats the output from the debug?

Comment: You won't need root permissions to write to the dir - In your code where is mineCraftDir set - and if you print it in MinecraftLoginThread what value does it have?

Comment: I have added the log to the main post

Comment: "Made new Minecraftt" is not printed in the log, is the code called at all?

Comment: Could you show the permissions for /Users/taylagaedicke/Library/Application Support/.melbvicminecraft? It is just to check that it is not a problem outside of your application.

Comment: Where is the code that logs "Failed to inject new minecraft location!"? The code you posted doesn't show the code that actually runs into the error.